# C: reading files which are > 4 GB

Tags: c, file, freebsd

I have some kind of reader which only has a handle (FILE*) to a file.
Another process keeps writing to a the same file which I don't have control.

Now, as the other process appends images to that file, it is likely that soon the file size will cross 4 GB limit.

The reader process reads that file using the handle, offset and length of the image file which can be found from some DB.

My question is how would reader be able to read the chunk from the file which will be present after 4GB size.

I'm working on Win32 machine.

EDIT:
I'm working on FreeBSD machine as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On FreeBSD the stdio API is not limited to 32 bits(4Gb).

You should have no problems reading past 4Gb as long as you use a 64 bit integer to manipulate the offsets and lengths.

If you're seeking in a FILE* , you'll have to use fseeko() and not fseek() if you're on a 32 bit host. fseek() takes a long which is 32 bit on 32 bit machines. fseeko() takes an `off_t` type which is 64 bits on all FreeBSD architectures.

Comment: Is it safe to use off_t like `sprintf(buf, "%ld", offset)`. I will be saving buf in DB.

Comment: @Mayank, no, that'll break if you're on a 32 bit host. Use `sprintf(buf, "%lld", (long long)offset);`

Answer (score 6):

Just use the standard C API on Windows, `fread`, `fwrite` work just fine on large files. You will need `_fseeki64` to seek to a 64-bit position.

You can alternatively use the plain WinAPI (`ReadFile`, etc.) which can also deal with >4 GiB files without problems.

[Edit]: The only thing you really need is a 64-bit seek, which `ReadFile` provides via the `OVERLAPPED` structure (as some commenters mentioned.) You can of course also get by using [`SetFilePointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is the equivalent of `_fseeki64`. Reading/Writing is never a problem, no matter the file size, only seeking.

Comment: ReadFile() rarely can deal with > 4GB files, not enough virtual memory.  Surely you meant SetFilePointerEx().

Comment: @Hans: `ReadFile` takes an `OVERLAPPED` parameter, `OVERLAPPED` has a 64-bit offset.  What's the problem?  And what does virtual memory have to do with it?

Comment: @David - you're right.  The lpDistanceToMoveHigh argument is kinda weird, never used it.

Comment: @ben the point is that you need the 64 bit support in the seek function rather than the read or write functionsk function rather than the read or write functions

Comment: @David Except with eg ReadFile() the seek is already included and works perfectly fine with sizes >4gb..

Comment: @voo the seek is typically done in one of the file pointer functions

Comment: Thanks all for the response. Is _fseeki64 Standard? I'm looking for something that works in FreeBSD.

Comment: Why this answer has 8 upvotes if it gives a windows solution and OP wants a FreeBSD solution?

Comment: @hexa: This is all my mistake. I wrote it Win32 by mistake. Later I edited it and modified it to FreeBSD quetion without mentioning the edit. I've corrected it. My apologies.